# Is a HostedService automatically scaled-out when AppService plan is autoscaling?

Tags: azure, asp.net-core-hosted-services

I have a .NET Core application running on Azure AppService.
I have also a hosted service interacting with a table and updating it according to a given condition.

I am experiencing an increase of CPU usage of just one of the instances when my autoscaling rules kick in and start scaling out the AppService.

My question is if HostedService is automatically scaled-out too when new instances are warmed up by autoscaling.

Answer (score 1):

Yes they are. When you scale out, you have multiple instances of the same application running.

I figured this out the hard way. I was running a hosted service that sent out reports through emails once a day. After I scaled out to 2 instances, clients started receiving the same email twice a day.

Comment: what is in youw way most elegant way of preventing email is sent multiple times (except removing scaling :) )